# Fragment causing skipped frames when screen is rotated

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a fragment, which displays more than 33 text views and a line chart. Screen rotation is very slow and Android Studio says this: "I/Choreographer: Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." The number of dropped frames increases with each new rotation. This doesn't happen if the data is displayed in the activity itself (i. e. not in a fragment). Even if I comment out every line of code that deals with data and leave only the minimal skeleton of the fragment, the problem persists.
I don't know what am I doing wrong, but since the problem persists even if no data is processed, I guess it's caused by the layout?

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    SensorDataFragment dataFragment = new SensorDataFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, dataFragment).commit();
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.sensor_data_fragment, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Activity layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/device_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlinkyActivity"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/connection_state"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="@string/state_connecting"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/not_supported"
        layout="@layout/info_not_supported"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/spect_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:cardElevation="1dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/spect_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/spect_tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:logo="@drawable/outline_opacity_24"
                app:title="@string/title_spectrum"
                app:titleMarginStart="@dimen/toolbar_title_margin" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spect_summary"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="@string/spectrum_summary"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spect_tool_bar" />

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/spect_chart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spect_summary" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_numberformat"
                android:contentDescription="@string/menu_number_format_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:onClick="showNumberFormatPopup"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/outline_more_horiz_24"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spect_chart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sensor_label_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="@string/sensor_label_1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/f1_label"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spect_chart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sensor_label_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:text="@string/sensor_label_2"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/sensor_label_1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spect_chart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sensor_label_3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:text="@string/sensor_label_3"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/sensor_label_2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spect_chart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/f1_label"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:text="@string/f1_data_label"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sensor_label_1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/s1f1_data"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:text="@string/spectrum_unknown"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/sensor_label_1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sensor_label_1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/sensor_label_1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sensor_label_1" />
// a lot of more text views
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can it be caused by the layout? I mean, if there's no data processed, what else can cause the problem? Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android system render 60 frame per seconds. It means each 16 ms screen redraw. (1000 / 60 = 16.6)

As we could read about efficient layout hierarchies, do not make a lot of nested viewgroup. [Read more](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout).

Also consider [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout), for relative positioning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Interesting thing is, that the same thing runs smoothly in the activity, but runs slow and drops frames in a fragment. The exact same code.

Comment: @Steve Because with fragment, some time fragmentmanager took for showing fragment. Fragment transaction is still UI operation.

Answer (score 1):

A choreographer can only detect the frame skipping. It has no way of telling why this happens.

but I think the problem happened because of heavy data processed in your fragment

The best way is to do all the processing in a thread separate from main UI thread to access your data then draw it

also this behavior of repeating view like "TextView" with same properties, not a good idea better to user RecyclerView and pass a list of your data to the recycler adapter

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, so many text views are not a good idea to have, but in this case I cannot use recycle view I think. I display data points in a table-like format in each text view.